# Java Reg-Ex pattern of stringA OR stringB

Tags: java, regex

So I know that pattern compilation for regular expression in java has OR statement of characters, like [abc] means 'a' or 'b' or 'c', but is there any way of saying

"helloWorld" or "goodbyeEveryone"?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html

Comment: How do you know what a character class is but not alternation? I thought 'alternation' came before character class in the beginners guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The regex would be `"helloWorld|goodbyeEveryone"`

The `|` symbol is basically the "or" operator in regex